# Count duplicates in an array of objects and sum up values located in the objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const users = [{name: 'John', gender: 'Male', orders: 20},
    {name: 'Doe', gender: 'Male', orders: 8},
    {name: 'Ada', gender: 'Female', orders: 10},
    {name: 'David', gender: 'Male', orders: 30}];
```

I need to count the number of duplicate genders and sum up the amount of orders based on *gender* located in the objects. I would like the final array to look like this:

```
[{gender: 'Male', count: 3, totalOrders: 58}, {gender: 'Female', count: 1, totalOrders: 10}]
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
const usersGender = users.map((user) => user.gender);

const result = Object.values(usersGender.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b] = a[b] || [b, 0];
  a[b][1]++;
  return a;
},{})).map(item => ({gender: item[0], count : item[1]}));

console.log(result);
```

My output from the code above is:

```
[{ gender: 'Male', count: 3 }, { gender: 'Female', count: 1 }]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could collect with an object and get the values from it.

```js
const
    users = [{ name: 'John', gender: 'Male', orders: 20 }, { name: 'Doe', gender: 'Male', orders: 8 }, { name: 'Ada', gender: 'Female', orders: 10 }, { name: 'David', gender: 'Male', orders: 30 }],
    result = Object.values(users.reduce((r, { gender, orders }) => {
        r[gender] ??= { gender, count: 0, totalOrders: 0 };
        r[gender].count++;
        r[gender].totalOrders += orders;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```